# Add requierd to bind-attr in ember.js?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I try to pass some attributes to an input-field using embers bind-attr.

```
<input {{bind-attr requierd="field.requierd" type="field.type" name="field.key" id="field.name"}} />
```

All but requierd work. I assume ember has some sort of list of allowed attributes. Is it possible to add new ones?

Someone had a similair problem and used, though TextField, doesn't seem to be the thing I should extend.

```
App.TextField = Ember.TextField.extend({
    attributeBindings:  ['required'],
    required:           null
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the right train dude. Reference [DOCS here](http://emberjs.com/guides/views/customizing-a-views-element/#toc_attribute-bindings-on-a-view). Things went wrong because of using bare input tags. Use the extended `text-field component` or more cleaner way is to register it as a helper and use it in hbs

```
App.TextField = Em.TextField.extend({
  attributeBindings: ['required']
});

Em.Handlebars.helper('input',App.TextField);
```

**Updated**

[Demo Working](http://jsfiddle.net/selvaG/u6ayc/2/)

Comment: This works, though I get the error "Assertion failed: You tried to register a component named 'input', but component names must include a '-'"

Comment: Component name should be dasherized